# Angular2 FormArray custom validator function not affecting "valid" property

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators

I have an Angular2 app and I've built a little dynamic-form module that allows me to build complex forms using the model-based approach.

One of the components I have allows me to pass in a list of FormObject instances and it then proceeds to throw them in a FormArray. I've created the following custom validator function

```
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

export function allExceptLastOneValidator (c: FormArray): { [key: string] : any} {

    if (c.controls.length < 2) {
        return null;
    }

    for (let i: number = 0; i < c.controls.length-1; i++) {
        if (!c.controls[i].valid) {
            return {
                allExceptLastOneValid: false
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I am then using it like this

```
this.formElement.setControl("models", new FormArray([], allExceptLastOneValidator));
```

The idea of this validator is that I want it to validate all FormGroup instances in the FormArray except the last one (since the last one is always blank/new and a new one gets added automatically the moment the last invalid entry becomes valid).

If I do `myFormArray.valid` however, I get that the form array is still invalid even though my validator returns null. The reason for this is that it still validates the last FormGroup which as I said will always be invalid.

My custom validator is getting triggered correctly and it's working fine (I debugged it). The problem is that it doesn't seem to affect the `FormArray.valid` property.

Could someone explain what is the purpose of the FormArray.validator function? I couldn't find any documentation on the matter and I thought it's supposed to override the validation of a FormGroup/FormArray completely but apparently that's not the case. Is this a bug or am I mistaken in my assumptions?